# Pig Help: Splitting a Field into Multiple Fields

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Hi I am playing around with Pig for the first time and am curious how to deal with splitting up a field into multiple other fields.

I have a bag, A, like the one below:

```
grunt> Dump A; 

(text, text, Mon Mar 07 12:00:00 CDT 2016)
```

What I'd like to do is split the Date-Time field into multiple fields so that I can explore the distribution of the data set and do group bys on the Day of Week, Month, Year, etc.

I have been looking at tokenize but am unsure this meets my needs as I need/want to have field names added to the bag or create a nested bag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the value is already of datatype datetime, then you could use the following functions to extract individual elements.Builtin function reference [DateTime Functions in PIG](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#datetime-functions)

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,f2,
                      GetDay(f3) as f3_Day,
                      GetMonth(f3) as f3_Month,
                      GetYear(f3) as f3_Year,
                      GetHour(f3) as f3_Hour,
                      GetMinute(f3) as f3_Minute,
                      GetSecond(f3) as f3_Second;
```

If the datatype is chararray then use the ToDate() function to convert it to  datetime and extract the date parts.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,f2,ToDate(f3,'choose your datetime format') as f3_Date;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE f1,f2,
                      GetDay(f3_Date) as f3_Day,
                      GetMonth(f3_Date) as f3_Month,
                      GetYear(f3_Date) as f3_Year,
                      GetHour(f3_Date) as f3_Hour,
                      GetMinute(f3_Date) as f3_Minute,
                      GetSecond(f3_Date) as f3_Second;
```